# Is it possible to switch between Views in a traitsui class?

Tags: python, traits

I'm writing a GUI program in python with TraitsUI from Enthought. I want to be able to switch between different Views of the same object in response to a user's action. Is it possible to do that?

The following approximately demonstrates what I want to do:

```py
from enthought.traits.api import HasTraits, Button
from enthought.traits.ui.api import View, Item

class Test(HasTraits):
    button1 = Button('Button 1')
    button2 = Button('Button 2')
    button3 = Button('Button 3')

    traits_view = View(Item('button1'), Item('button2'))
    view2 = View(Item('button1'), Item('button3'))

    def _button1_fired(self):
        #select view2
        pass

    def _button3_fired(self):
        #select traits_view
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = Test()
    test.configure_traits()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can achieve the effect you desire not by switching views but by use of the visible_when keyword in the definition of a Group that's part of your view. There is some inspiration in the examples:
[examples/demo/Dynamic_Forms/visible_when.py](https://github.com/enthought/traitsui/blob/729c5d3d33b7aa44a8bdd212622bab23fe3e87e9/examples/demo/Dynamic_Forms/visible_when.py)